# C# Selenium Function to take user input and click on xpath text containing "&nbsp;"?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

I am writing a function that is supposed to take in a string, and click on the html element containing text matching the string.

But in some cases, the element's text contains the special characters &nbsp, and my function fails to find the element.

I posted my current solution below which I found in another post, but this does not work either. I've also tried normalize-space, but that only works for space characters, and not &nbsp

```
        public static void ClickOnItem(string itemName)
        {
            IWebElement target = BrowserUtility.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//div[translate(.,'\u00A0','')='{0}']",itemName)));
            TestUtility.ClickElement(target);
        }
```

The HTML element I am trying to click on looks like this:

```
<div>Foo&nbsp;Doo&nbsp;Item</div>
```

Ideally, the user would pass 'Foo Doo Item' into the function, and the function would click on the div element.

Any help on if this is possible would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to replace spaces with non-breaking spaces. You can type a non-breaking space on Windows with `Alt+0160`. Warning, in your code editor this will likely look exactly the same as a regular space, so the maintainability of your code will go down.

```
string input = "some user input";
string adjustedInput = input.Replace(" ", " "); // replace space with nb-space
IWebElement target = BrowserUtility.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[text()='{adjustedInput}']"));
            TestUtility.ClickElement(target);
```

Comment: Wow that is very strange, but that worked. Did not know about the ALT sequence stuff. Thank you!